# How can I unmerge cell in a specific row using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls

How can I unmerge cell form this code:

```
worksheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
                        getRow, //first row (0-based)
                        getRow, //last row  (0-based)
                        1, //first column (0-based)
                        2  //last column  (0-based)
                ));
```

I tried replacing the fourth argument '2' to '1'.

Comment: Have you tried with removeMergedRegion()? https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#removeMergedRegion-int-

Comment: Yes, but upon trying removeMergedRegion() it radomly removes merged regions in my sheet and destroys the format... while I just want to remove a specific merged region.

Comment: It's causing no trouble for me. Could you please show how are you using removeMergedRegion(), and what 's the problem it's causing?

Comment: `Sheet.removeMergedRegion(int index)` removes the merged region at `index`. So you need to determine the index of that merged region you wants to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it, maybe you are using removeMergedRegion() wrong.

```
        // Merge some cells
        spreadsheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,0,1));
        spreadsheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,1,0,1));
        spreadsheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,2,3));
        
        // Get all merged cells in document
        List<CellRangeAddress> lst = new ArrayList<CellRangeAddress>(spreadsheet.getMergedRegions());
        for(CellRangeAddress c : lst) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
        
        // Remove the first(index 0) merged region
        spreadsheet.removeMergedRegion(0);
        System.out.println("-------");
        
        // See how it has been removed
        lst = new ArrayList<CellRangeAddress>(spreadsheet.getMergedRegions());
        for(CellRangeAddress c : lst) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
```

Output:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [A1:B1]
org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [A2:B2]
org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [C1:D1]
-------
org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [A2:B2]
org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [C1:D1]
```

Excel:

[image]

Note that the first merged cell `A1:B1` is no longer merged, and it has not affected the other ones, even though they are on the same row and column.

**EDIT**

What you asked in the last comment:

> So you need to determine the index of that merged region you wants to
> remove.

```
            // Search index by position
            List<CellRangeAddress> lst = new ArrayList<CellRangeAddress>(spreadsheet.getMergedRegions());
            int i = 0;
            for(CellRangeAddress c : lst) {
                // replace the numbers with the ones matching the
                // merged cell you want to remove
                if(c.getFirstRow() == 1 &&
                    c.getFirstColumn() == 0 &&
                    c.getLastRow() == 1 &&
                    c.getLastRow() == 1)
                System.out.println(c);
                i++;
            }
            
            spreadsheet.removeMergedRegion(i);
```

Comment: Does the index of the method removeMergedRegion() in columns or in rows? Because I'm locating the index base on the row of the merged region I want to unmerged.

Comment: @RyanChristopherEdquila The index is the nth merged region. It has nothing to do with number of columns/rows. For example, you can have a merged region in the 15th row from first to third columns. If that is the only merged region in the sheet, that would be index 0, because it is the first merged region. Now, if you have a lot of merged regions you can use the loop I have provided to find the index of a merged region based on the position of the merged cell you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not pretty clear about what data you know to determine which merged region shall be removed from sheet.

If you know for example that there is a special `CellRangeAddress` which is a merged region but shall not, then one could have a method `removeMergedRegion(Sheet sheet, CellRangeAddress mergedRegionToRemove)`. To do this one must traversing all merged region in the sheet using an index (`i`). If the `CellRangeAddress` of the found merged region equals the searched  `CellRangeAddress`, the the `i` points to the correct index and `sheet.removeMergedRegion(i)` can be used.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

class ExcelRemoveMergedRegion {
    
 static boolean removeMergedRegion(Sheet sheet, CellRangeAddress mergedRegionToRemove) {
  boolean removed = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
   CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
   if (mergedRegionToRemove.equals(mergedRegion)) {
    sheet.removeMergedRegion(i);
    removed = true;
    break;
   }
  }
  return removed;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelHavingMergedCells.xlsx")); String fileOutPath = "./ExcelHavingMergedCellsNew.xlsx";
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelHavingMergedCells.xls")); String fileOutPath = "./ExcelHavingMergedCellsNew.xls";

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  
  CellRangeAddress mergedRegionToRemove = new CellRangeAddress(1,3,1,1); //B2:B4
  boolean removed = removeMergedRegion(sheet, mergedRegionToRemove);
  if (removed) System.out.println("Merged region " + mergedRegionToRemove + " was removed");
  else System.out.println("Region " + mergedRegionToRemove + " was not merged");
      
  mergedRegionToRemove = new CellRangeAddress(0,0,4,6); //E1:G1
  removed = removeMergedRegion(sheet, mergedRegionToRemove);
  if (removed) System.out.println("Merged region " + mergedRegionToRemove + " was removed");
  else System.out.println("Region " + mergedRegionToRemove + " was not merged");
 
  mergedRegionToRemove = new CellRangeAddress(9,10,1,2); //B10:C11
  removed = removeMergedRegion(sheet, mergedRegionToRemove);
  if (removed) System.out.println("Merged region " + mergedRegionToRemove + " was removed");
  else System.out.println("Region " + mergedRegionToRemove + " was not merged");
   
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileOutPath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Note: There are no methods to change the cell range of merged regions. It that is the need, then at first remove the old merged region and then create a new merged region having wanted cell range.